# Is it possible to generate addresses for other cryptos using waves api?

Tags: cryptocurrency, wavesplatform

I recently got into learning about the waves platform and its various API's.
I want to know if it was possible to generate addresses for other cryptos like bitcoin or ethereum on it.

Also, if it is possible to send crypto to addresses from other wallets.

I've looked at document [here](https://github.com/wavesplatform/waves-transactions) but its documentation is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Which Waves api/lib are you refering to ? 
What you mean by " send crypto to addresses from other wallets" ? what type of addresses/wallets ? waves ? be more precise so we can help better.

Answer (score 0):

The other currencies within waves are there because coinomats gateways.
Coinomat has an api available: https://coinomat.com/api.php
I never used it myself/ don't know how powerfull it is, but I guess this is what you are looking for?
However since coinomat is third party, it's always harder to work with these api's then when you want to generate just a waves address.

Are there any adventages or reasons why you want to generate btc/.. addr?
Or what is the exact purpose?